# Combining 2 complex queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, union

First of all, I cannot provide a SQL Fiddle because data is really complex to be recreated. I will try to present the queries, outputs, and questions as clear as possible.

I have query that looks-like this:

```
with cte(MainArt,secondaryArt, Quantity) as(
SELECT t_mitm, t_sitm, t_qana
            FROM ttibom010201 
        WHERE TRIM(t_mitm) = 'ACL-4812070395-4'
union all
select 
ttibom010201.t_mitm, ttibom010201.t_sitm, ttibom010201.t_qana
from ttibom010201 inner join cte on cte.secondaryArt=ttibom010201.t_mitm
        )
select    cte.* ,dsc.t_cuni, dsc.t_dsca from cte
left join ttcibd001201 dsc on dsc.t_item = cte.secondaryArt 
where TRIM(secondaryArt)  like N'30%'
```

This exact query returns me these 4 rows:

[image]

From a different table I use this **secondArt** value to get some info:

```
select top 1 t_orno, t_item,t_pric from ttdpur401201 where t_item like '%30102024%' order by  t_ddte desc
```

The result is:

[image]

As you can see t_item and secondaryArt are the same (3rd and 4th row from the first query). So I want to be able somehow to merge these 2 queries into 1. In the first table, I only need to add this **t_pric**.

How can I merge these two queries?

Comment: Why tag MySQL and SQL Server? Please only tag the one you are using.

Comment: Sounds like a simple join to me. Please explain in more detail what results you expect, and consider providing simple sample data (e.g. treat the results of both as simple tables) and the expected result for that sample data.

Comment: What will be your final output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a left join between two queries will do the trick.

```
  with cte(MainArt,secondaryArt, Quantity) as(
SELECT t_mitm, t_sitm, t_qana
            FROM ttibom010201 
        WHERE TRIM(t_mitm) = 'ACL-4812070395-4'
union all
select 
ttibom010201.t_mitm, ttibom010201.t_sitm, ttibom010201.t_qana
from ttibom010201 inner join cte on cte.secondaryArt=ttibom010201.t_mitm
        )
select    cte.* ,dsc.t_cuni, dsc.t_dsca, t_pric from cte
left join ttcibd001201 dsc on dsc.t_item = cte.secondaryArt 
Left join (select  t_orno, t_item,t_pric from ttdpur401201 inner join cte on t_item like cte.secondaryArt order by  t_ddte desc) t
on cte.secondaryArt = t.t_item
where TRIM(secondaryArt)  like N'30%'
```

New modified answer:

```
with cte(MainArt,secondaryArt, Quantity) as(
SELECT t_mitm, t_sitm, t_qana
            FROM ttibom010201 
        WHERE TRIM(t_mitm) = 'ACL-4812070395-4'
union all
select 
ttibom010201.t_mitm, ttibom010201.t_sitm, ttibom010201.t_qana
from ttibom010201 inner join cte on cte.secondaryArt=ttibom010201.t_mitm
        )
select    cte.* ,dsc.t_cuni, dsc.t_dsca, t_pric from cte
left join ttcibd001201 dsc on dsc.t_item = cte.secondaryArt 
Left join (select top 1 t_orno, t_item,t_pric,row_number()over(partition by t_item order by t_ddte desc) rnfrom ttdpur401201 ) t
on t.t_item like cte.secondaryArt  and t.rn=1
where TRIM(secondaryArt)  like N'30%'
```

Comment: @Borislav Stefanov Please let us know if you problem has not been resolved yet.

Comment: Hi. All the items have results in the ttdpur401201 table. I need to join this table but without this part WHERE t_item LIKE '%30102024%' . For every row has to have t_pric from ttdpur401201. Not resolved yet

Comment: Basically if it is possible this          WHERE  t_item LIKE '%30102024%' to become          WHERE  t_item LIKE  cte.secondaryArt somehow

Comment: You can use WHERE t_item LIKE cte.secondaryArt. I have revised my answer.

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The multi-part identifier "cte.secondaryArt" could not be bound.

Comment: Giving me error. Seems to be not that simple

Comment: Sorry, I didn't join the cte in subquery query. Try it now.

Comment: I am afraid that this query will run but might not give you the result you are expecting. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: if previous answer doesn't work then please try new modified answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230212/discussion-between-borislav-stefanov-and-kazi-mohammad-ali-nur).

Answer (score 2):

I think this query can work:

```
WITH cte(MainArt,secondaryArt, Quantity) AS (
    SELECT t_mitm, t_sitm, t_qana
    FROM ttibom010201 
    WHERE TRIM(t_mitm) = 'ACL-4812070395-4'
        
    UNION ALL

    SELECT ttibom010201.t_mitm, ttibom010201.t_sitm, ttibom010201.t_qana
    FROM ttibom010201 
    INNER JOIN cte ON cte.secondaryArt=ttibom010201.t_mitm
)
        
SELECT cte.* ,dsc.t_cuni, dsc.t_dsca, aux.t_pric1
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN ttcibd001201 dsc ON dsc.t_item = cte.secondaryArt 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT t_orno, t_item, FIRST_VALUE(t_pric) OVER (PARTITION BY t_orno, t_item ORDER BY t_ddte DESC) AS t_pric1 FROM ttdpur401201) AS aux ON aux.t_item = cte.secondaryArt
WHERE TRIM(secondaryArt) LIKE N'30%'
```

Comment: It is the same as Kazi Mohammad answer. Yes, it works

Comment: It is similar, not the same. I realized it later, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i exactly know what you want, but i would try something like

```
with cte( MainArt, secondaryArt, Quantity) as (
    select 
     t_mitm, 
     t_sitm, 
     t_qana
    from ttibom010201 
    where trim(t_mitm) = 'ACL-4812070395-4'
    union all
    select 
     ttibom010201.t_mitm, 
     ttibom010201.t_sitm, 
     ttibom010201.t_qana
    from ttibom010201 
    inner join cte on cte.secondaryArt = ttibom010201.t_mitm
)
select cte.*, dsc.t_cuni, dsc.t_dsca 
from cte
left join ttcibd001201 dsc on dsc.t_item = cte.secondaryArt
left join ( 
    select 
     t_orno, 
     t_item, 
     t_pric 
    from ttdpur401201 
    group by 
     t_orno, 
     t_item, 
     t_price 
    order by t_ddte desc
) i on i.t_item = cte.secondaryArt
where trim(secondaryArt) like N'30%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
WITH cte1(mainart, secondaryart, quantity)
     AS (SELECT t_mitm,
                t_sitm,
                t_qana
         FROM   ttibom010201
         WHERE  Trim(t_mitm) = 'ACL-4812070395-4'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ttibom010201.t_mitm,
                ttibom010201.t_sitm,
                ttibom010201.t_qana
         FROM   ttibom010201
                INNER JOIN cte1
                        ON cte1.secondaryart = ttibom010201.t_mitm),
     cte2
     AS (SELECT TOP 1 t_orno,
                      t_item,
                      t_pric
         FROM   ttdpur401201
         WHERE  t_item LIKE '%30102024%'
         ORDER  BY t_ddte DESC)
SELECT cte1.*,
       dsc.t_cuni,
       dsc.t_dsca,
       cte2.t_pric
FROM   cte1
       LEFT JOIN ttcibd001201 dsc
              ON dsc.t_item = cte1.secondaryart
       LEFT JOIN cte2
              ON cte1.secondaryart = cte2.t_item
WHERE  Trim(secondaryart) LIKE N'30%'
```

**Expected result:** The above should add an extra column `t_pric` to your original query as follows:

| t_pric |
| --- |
| `NULL` |
| `NULL` |
| `1.4` |
| `1.4` |

Comment: Hi. All the items have results in the ttdpur401201 table. I need to join this table but without this part          WHERE  t_item LIKE '%30102024%' . For every row has to have t_pric from ttdpur401201

Comment: Basically if it is possible this          WHERE  t_item LIKE '%30102024%' to become          WHERE  t_item LIKE  cte1.secondaryArt somehow

Comment: Sounds doable but please could you edit your question first to include these requirements?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of the cardinality of `ttibom010201` and `ttdpur401201` but you could potentially join the `ttdpur401201` table in the CTE to get the price.

```
with cte(MainArt,secondaryArt, Quantity, Price) as (
SELECT t_mitm, t_sitm, t_qana, t_pric
            FROM ttibom010201 b join ttdpur401201 p ON b.t_sitm = p.t_item 
)
```

The same applies for the second half of the CTE query.